# Recovery of zeroed first 27MB of disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, partition-recovery

I have laptop with SSD inside. Externally I have 750GB disk connected via USB 2.0.

I was trying to zero pendrive using Cygwin -

```
pv /dev/zero > ...
```

but zeroed about 27MB of 750GB disk, not pendrive. Drive wasn't detached. Then I runn chkdsk for this 750GB disk. It found a little errors and was able to read data from it. Then I detached this disk and reattached it. MBR was missing. Data is on the disk, I know. diskmgmt.msc was asking to create MBR, I agreed.

Now the disk has MBR, there is data on it, but diskmgmt.msc sees that there are no partitions. If recreating the MBR didn't changed MFT, the data can be restored. So, now I have (I think) fine MBR, but with no partitions defined, data and MFT are on the disk. What should I do now to restore access to this data (important)? Fixmbr and fixboot does not see the drive letter, so they can't be used.

I've tried GParted and its recovery option, but it reads the disk on and on without any effects.

Comment: Please stop doing things to the drive and take a full image backup of the drive before you do anything else. Each of those things you did may have overwritten data that you now have no change of ever getting back.

Comment: You are completely right, but I have no option to copy the data - I don't had any other disk I would copy the data to. This was very risky, but I restored the partiton.

Comment: You didn't back up the data. You didn't follow common sense procedures to recover it after a loss. Yet you maintain the data is important. It reminds me of a story: A guy goes to the doctor. The doctor says, "The best thing for your health would be if you stopped drinking so heavily, stopped smoking, lost weight, and exercised more". The guy asks, "What's would be the second best thing?"

Comment: Sometimes some solutions are not possible and require some sort of risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so using "MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition" and scanning for lost partitons did the trick. I can see all the data on the disk. Now have to run chkdsk on this disk only.

Comment: This application was first found by me and I tried.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to recover your data. Now, start making those backups before we take away your compter licence. ;)

Comment: I've already had backup on other disks. Problematic would be to copy entire 750GB anywhere else, while there are home limits for such a portion of data space.

Comment: There was problem with MFT, disk needed to be reformatted after this zeroing, as it was not functioning properly.